# Why is my function turning into a object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I have several ajax requests in my project so to simplify my code i created a function to handle the requests.

I am passing a success function to load when status is == 200 however even though the data is being sent correctly i am receiving "uncaught type error success is not a function" error. Using typeof i can see success starts as a function but then displays as an object.

[image]

here is my code

//function to handle ajax requests

```
function sendRequest(link, requestType, success, data) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = link;

    request.open(requestType, url, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            console.log("success");

            var responseText = request.responseText;
            console.log(typeof(success));

            success(responseText);
        } else {
            consoloe.log("error");
        }
    }

    request.send(data);
}
```

//calling function passing success function as argument

```
var jsonText = "json.php";

sendRequest(jsonText, 'GET', function (response) {
    var json = JSON.parse(response),
        postcodesArray = [],
        jsonLength = json.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
        postcodesArray.push(json[i].from_postcode);
    }

    var postcodes = postcodesArray.filter(Boolean),
        pstcodeLength = postcodes.length,
        n;

    for (n = 0; n < pstcodeLength; n++) {
        geocodeAddress(postcodes[n]);
    }
});
```

//EDIT fiddle containing all my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/x1qe73s8/

Comment: I can't see any errors in the script you posted. Are you sure that is the ONLY place where you are sending requests from? I mean... maybe somewhere else in your script you have something like: "sendRequest(something, 'GET', new Object());"

Comment: Please post all your code, maybe you redefine something in another part of your code.

Comment: I have posted all the code above @zozo I am sending another request in a different function but why would that matter?

Comment: "why would that matter?" in case it's really that other function which is firing and causing the error and not this one.

Comment: @Sai Because the request you posted looks fine, and since that is a closure it can only be a function there (nowhere is changed). BUT if you call the sendRequest function from another place there may be a problem there. The console doesn't know or care where your function was called from and with what parameters. For that you need to log the parameters.

Comment: @Sai So... I was right. The other call is the issue (Jerome posted the answer). sendRequest(url, 'POST', null, data); is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your jsfiddle, your code is probably going through the sendLatLng function where you have

```
sendRequest(url, 'POST', null, data);
```

typeof null is "object".

Comment: Can you pls. expand that? Can't see any sendLatLng in the posted script.

Comment: see the jsfiddle that the OP added.

Comment: Ah... yes... you are right. Is obvious there :). (the fiddle was edited after)

Comment: Oh silly mistake, I put null as a argument because that request is only posting data and doesn't need a success. Is it correct to just put an empty function?

Comment: @Sai not if you don't then handle the possibility! But otherwise it's kind of ok. Personally I'd always want to have a "success" callback (and an "error" one, to customise the error handling, which your system doesn't seem to support), even if it just logs something to the console to prove it worked.